# Persist Breeze Entities through Page Reloads

Tags: breeze

If I use Breeze to retrieve data:

```
var manager = new breeze.EntityManager(SERVICE_NAME);
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from(ENTITY_NAME);
var entities = [];

entityManager.executeQuery(query).then(function(data){
     entities = data.results;
});
```

then need to persist `entities` from one page to the next (i.e. page reload, redirect, etc.) to allow more data to be added to the entities through something like a form wizard, how would I go about storing `entities` so that another trip to the database isn't necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Leverage localStorage, see more here http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/export-import.html